# 128 bits variable operations

Tags: c++, 128-bit

In c++ (Linux, without using boost).

I have 2 64 bits variables (long long) (say x and y).

when I'm doing x*y the result may be 128 bits.
How can I store it ? is there a variable that define a 128 bits ?

(I need a specific variable of 128 bits, because later in my program I may use the "/" operations on that 128 bit variable )

Thank's

Comment: What about using doubles?

Comment: There should be some "infinite precision" (or "extended precision") packages floating around, that permit integers (and floats) wider than the hardware and native language support. It's software emulation, so it's slow, and you may not have literals that size.

Comment: Looks like GCC still has an `int128_t` that should work from what I can tell.

Comment: what are you doing that would require more than 64bit ints? check out https://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) GCC extension:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
    long long a, b, c;

    a = 9223372036854775807LL;
    b = 3;
    c = 5;

    __int128 r = (__int128) a * b;

    c = r / c;

    printf("%lld\n", c); // 5534023222112865484
}
```

Note that explicit cast **is required** for multiplication (i.e. to "force" `__int128` type for operands). As long as you have 64-bit target it should work that way. To confirm check your result with e.g. `bc`:

```
$ echo "9223372036854775807*3/5" | bc
5534023222112865484
```

You might also try some arbitratry precision library like [`GMP`](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: This is documented here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html including a description of the conditions required for it to work.

Comment: Right, linked, thanks :-)